# Is it possible to specify an activity to be created when the OS resumes an app it has previously killed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity to be run when the user launches the app and is specified in the manifest as follows:

```
<activity android:name="redacted.activity.UserLaunch" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If the OS kills the application (it will do this in M if the user revokes previously granted permissions) then when the user relaunches it by tapping on the last displayed activity from the square button the OS doesn't create the **UserLaunch** activity, instead it calls `onCreate()` on whatever activity was previously displayed when the app was killed.
Is there a way of specifying in the manifest that the **UserLaunch** activity should get created in this situation?

Comment: Does `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` have the desired effect?

Comment: No thats already present in the manifest but isn't having the desired effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the particular situation with revoked permissions in M, but here's an approach we took when we wanted to do this whenever the system had killed the activity to free up memory.

When the system kills the Activity and then the user goes back to the app as you describe [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) is called after onCreate and onStart. So try overriding it like so:

```
    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // put code here for what you actually want to happen
    // instead of restoring the Activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of specifying in the manifest that the UserLaunch activity should get created in this situation?

I don't know. However I think you can achieve the same result by querying the `Intent` in `onCreate`. If `Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(getIntent().getAction())` then it means that the `Activity` was started for this reason. In this situation you can just start `UserLaunch` yourself and immediately call `finish()` on the `Activity` you don't want.